# Apache not allowing .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS and Apache to 2.4. When the server first started back up I was getting 403 errors visiting pages. This is when I learned I needed to change to `Require all granted`. I thought I had everything working till I realized `.htaccess` was not being loaded anywhere. I thought that needed to be changed as well, but the Apache docs says it's fine from what I can find. Below is my `Directory` rule currently.

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/hosts/%-2.0.%-1.0/%-3+/public_html
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/hosts/[^/]+/[^/]+/public_html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</DirectoryMatch>
```

My first thought was the regex was wrong and none of the rules were being loaded. So I commented out the `Require all granted` and saw it stopped websites from loading again. So I knew it was loading them. I had to do the below to get them to work.

```
<Directory /var/hosts/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Am I ok to leave it with this? Any thoughts why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

It seems Apache 2.4 has issues with `[^/]+` to match a directory. I was able to make it work with `*` instead. It matches everything but a `/`.

I had come across this issue again with trying to secure any subdomain of `dev`. I saw that specifying the domain instead of using REGEX would work within the VirtualHost.

After looking over the [Directory docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) I learned about `*` and gave it a shot. Also learned that `DirectoryMatch` does not affect subdirectories and that `Directory` allows REGEX.

Comment: "Apache 2.4 has issues with `[^/]+`" - Hhhm, no it doesn't? Do you have a reference? It does if you are using a vanilla `<Directory>` directive (that accepts _wildcards_ only). But a `<DirectoryMatch>` directives (as stated in the question) takes a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Configure Apache mod_rewrite

   ```
   a2enmod rewrite
   ```
2. add the following code to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   ```
3. Restart Apache

   ```
   /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: That module is already enabled and I already have `AllowOverride All` in my default. That's the first `<DirectoryMatch>` above.

Comment: How did you make .htaccess file? ( if windows id you convert or save correct) who has access to the file? any error in logs?

Comment: The .htaccess files worked before I upgraded. I noticed websites that used them, it was being ignored. So I modified one so that it should throw a 500 error. I didn't get the expected result till I added the over arching `<Directory /var/hosts/>`. So I don't see it as a permission issue. I couldn't find any errors in the logs.

Comment: what is in .htaccess file?